# How to get array of objects only if array values matches with object array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have array `arr1, arr2, arr3` and object array `objarr`

I would like to get array of objects based on condition

i.e
when passing arr1,
object array `objarr` should return only matched keys of `arr1`

i.e
when passing arr2,
object array `objarr` should return only matched keys of `arr2` (if `wrk` is passed parameter only show that is true )

i.e
when passing arr3,
object array `objarr` should return only matched keys of `arr3`

```
var arr1=["name", "place"]
var arr2=["details", "wrk"]
var arr3=["name"]

var objarr=[
  {id:1, name: "ayan", place: "MY", details: "finance" , wrk: true},
  {id:2, name: "mike", place: "AU", details: "teaching", wrk: false },
  {id:3, name: "john", place: "DE", details: "service" , wrk: true}
]

function outputData(arr1){
  var final=[];
  var result = objarr.map(e=>{
   if(arr1.includes(Object.keys(e)){
    final.push(e)
   }
  })

return  final
;}

Expected Output;
//for arr1 is passed
[
  {name: "ayan", place: "MY"},
  {name: "mike", place: "AU"},
  {name: "john", place: "DE"}
]

//for arr2 is passed
[
  {details: "finance", wrk:true},
  {details: "service", wrk: true}
]

//for arr3 is passed
[
  {name: "ayan"},
  {name: "mike"},
  {name: "john"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = ["name", "place"];
var arr2 = ["details", "wrk"];
var arr3 = ["name"];

var objarr = [
  { id: 1, name: "ayan", place: "MY", details: "finance", wrk: true },
  { id: 2, name: "mike", place: "AU", details: "teaching", wrk: false },
  { id: 3, name: "john", place: "DE", details: "service", wrk: true }
]

function outputData(arr) {
  var final = [];
  objarr.forEach(obj => {
      const temp = {};
      arr.forEach(key => {
          if(obj[key]){
              temp[key]= obj[key];
          }
      });
      if(Object.keys(temp).length===arr.length){
      final.push(temp);}
  });

  return final;
}
console.log('arr1',outputData(arr1));
console.log('arr2',outputData(arr2));
console.log('arr3',outputData(arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to select only specific nodes from `objarr`, going for `Array.map` willnot give the result. Use Some other looping logic for that.

I used `Array.reduce` here.

Logic

- Loop through `objarr` with `Array.reduce`.
- Loop through the paremeter array inside the reduce.
- Check if the value for each node from the parameter array in the object in `objarr` array.
- If the value is truthy, add that to an object.
- If the length of keys of this object is same as the length of parameter array, push this object to accumulator.

**Please Note:** This logic checks truthy value for key "wrk" only. If you want to check for all boolean values, you can use the condition added as comment just above the if statement

```js
var arr1 = ["name", "place"]
var arr2 = ["details", "wrk"]
var arr3 = ["name"]

var objarr = [
  { id: 1, name: "ayan", place: "MY", details: "finance", wrk: true },
  { id: 2, name: "mike", place: "AU", details: "teaching", wrk: false },
  { id: 3, name: "john", place: "DE", details: "service", wrk: true }
]

function outputData(arr) {
  var result = objarr.reduce((acc, currNode) => {
    const resp = {};
    arr.forEach((option) => {
      // Current condition is only for "wrk"
      // To check truthy state for all boolean variables use the below condition
      // ((typeof currNode[option] === "boolean" && currNode[option]) || typeof currNode[option] !== "boolean")
      if ((option === "wrk" && currNode[option]) || option !== "wrk") {
        resp[option] = currNode[option]
      }
    })
    if(Object.keys(resp).length === arr.length) {
      acc.push(resp)
    }
    return acc
  }, []);
  return result;
}
console.log(outputData(arr1));
console.log(outputData(arr2));
console.log(outputData(arr3));
```

Comment: `arr2` doesn't give the result that OP wants

Comment: @decpk nice catch. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
var arr1 = ["name", "place"];
var arr2 = ["details", "wrk"];
var arr3 = ["name"];

var objarr = [
  { id: 1, name: "ayan", place: "MY", details: "finance", wrk: true },
  { id: 2, name: "mike", place: "AU", details: "teaching", wrk: false },
  { id: 3, name: "john", place: "DE", details: "service", wrk: true },
];

function getData(target, source) {
  return target.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const obj = {};
    for (let prop of source) {
      obj[prop] = curr[prop];
    }
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes("wrk")) {
      if (obj["wrk"]) acc.push(obj);
    } else acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getData(objarr, arr1));
console.log(getData(objarr, arr2));
console.log(getData(objarr, arr3));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
function outputData(arr) {
  return objarr.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(arr.map(k => [k, obj[k]])))
}
```

Comment: arr2 doesn't give the expected output.